# Keep the radio button hidden in html bydefault and unhide them using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to keep the radio buttons hidden in html. And later I want to unhide only a few of them using jquery. I know how to unhide using jquery. But I don't know if we can keep them hidden in html by default.

Comment: share with us what have you tried so far.

Comment: You can set display:none; in style sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use inline css

```
<input type="radio" style="display:none" id="rbhide"/>radio
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/QGfPv/1/)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?
jsfiddle.net/UQk2z/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#radio').hide();
});

$('#btn').onclick(function() {
  $('#radio').show();
});
```